# "Invalid class typecast" error when deriving from TTreeNode

Tags: delphi

I am trying to expand the `TTreeNode` class with some additional fields for my very simple program. Like this:

```
TCustomTreeNode = class(TTreeNode)
private
  FPath : string;
  FParam : string;

  property Path: string read FPath write FPath;
  property Param : string read FParam write FParam;
end;
```

And I tell `TTreeView` to use my class like this:

```
procedure TMain.cxTreeView1CreateNodeClass(Sender: TCustomTreeView;
  var NodeClass: TTreeNodeClass);
begin
  NodeClass := TCustomTreeNode;
end;
```

Then I define an Array of nodes, like this:

```
Nodes : array of TCustomTreeNode;
```

And finally, I tried to fill the array like this:

```
Nodes[i] := cxTreeView1.Items.Add(nil, OuterRoot.ChildNodes[i].AttributeNodes.Nodes['Name'].Text) as TCustomTreeNode;
```

It raises an "invalid class typecast" exception.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The tree control creates the nodes. You have to tell it to create your node class. Exactly how to do that depends on which tree class you are using. However, in my experience there are usually better ways to solve such problems than to use a custom node type.

Comment: procedure TMain.cxTreeView1CreateNodeClass(Sender: TCustomTreeView;
  var NodeClass: TTreeNodeClass);
begin
  NodeClass := TCustomTreeNode;
end;

Comment: Please don't ask the question in the comments. Edit the question to make it stand alone. Add a [mcve].

Comment: @user1937012 did you verify that `cxTreeView1CreateNodeClass()` is actually assigned to  `cxTreeView1`'s `OnCreateNodeClass` event? If it is not, that would explain your runtime error

Comment: sorry dthat was a mistake with the voting... I am making it really hard for myself to use this stackoverflow thing...